# Does the Oracle Database Built-in Password Protections prevent pass-the-hash or replay attacks?

Tags: passwords, databases, oracle

Does the Oracle Database Built-in Password Protections prevent pass-the-hash or replay attacks?

Reading the "What Are the Oracle Database Built-in Password Protections?" from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/authentication.htm#DBSEG30031 I see AES encryption is used as well as SHA-1 hashing.

I understand that data in-transit over the network is unencrypted, but the initial session setup and authentication is suppose to not send the password in the clear.

So **WITHOUT** using Oracle Advanced Security (for full network layer encryption) does the **built-in** method prevent pass-the-hash or replay attacks?

Is there some type of noonce?

I'm guessing the AES is done with the user's password or is the key exchanged some other way?

Comment: Advanced Security allows wrapping the connections in certificate based SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the TNS login process and not about the stored hashes. But just in case: Oracle up to 10 stored password hashes as simple 2-iteration DES over uppercased user+password since 11.1 it is a [salted SHA-1](http://blog.red-database-security.com/2007/09/21/oracle-password-algorithm-11g-poc-code/).

For the TNS Logins with password authentication (there are others like Kerberos), the protocol use a challenge response where the password hash is encrypted with a session key. Starting with 10g the session key is larger and contains a client and a server part (as opposed to only a server part before).

The most problematic aspect of this is, that if you have the password hash you can use it to [brute force](http://soonerorlater.hu/index.khtml?article_id=511) a sniffed login package.

So short answer to your question: yes (but it is not very secure).